# Collect prices with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to be able to add and display the amount when the numbers are entered using jQuery, as shown in the image below.
please guide me.

These are the html codes:

```
.tours_description_book {
  border: 1px solid #d2ac67;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 9px;
}
.tours_description_book .title {
  background: #0c1e3a;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 15px 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.tours_description_book > ul {
  display: grid;
  grid: auto / auto;
  padding: 15px 35px;
}
.tours_description_book > ul > li > ul {
  display: grid;
  grid: auto / 50% 50%;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.tours_description_book > ul > li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdddf;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  color: #0c1e3a;
}
.tours_description_book > ul > li > ul > li:last-of-type {
  text-align: center;
}
.tours_description_book > ul > li:first-of-type > ul > li:last-of-type {
  text-align: left;
}
.tours_description_book > ul > li:first-of-type {
  font-weight: 400;
}
.tours_description_book > ul > li:last-of-type {
  border: 0;
}
.tours_description .tours_description_book a {
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
  margin: 0 auto 50px;
  background: #0c1e3a;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 9px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 60px;
}
.tours_description .tours_description_book a:hover {
  background: #d2ac67;
}
input[type="number"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  appearance: textfield;
}
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.number-input {
  border: 1px solid #d2ac67;
  display: inline-flex;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.number-input,
.number-input * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.number-input button {
  outline:none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.number-input button:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '-';
  color: #d2ac67;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.number-input button.plus:before {
  content: '+';
}
.number-input input[type=number] {
  max-width: 4rem;
  padding: .5rem;
  border: solid #d2ac67;
  border-width: 0 1px;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 3rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
                        <div class="tours_description_book wrapper">
                            <div class="title wrapper">- Booking -</div>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Adults
                                            <div class="number-input cart-free">
                                                <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('.Adults_N').stepDown()" ></button>
                                                <input class="quantity Adults_N" min="0" name="Adults" value="1" type="number">
                                                <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('.Adults_N').stepUp()" class="plus"></button>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>Children
                                            <div class="number-input cart-free">
                                                <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('.Children_N').stepDown()" ></button>
                                                <input class="quantity Children_N" min="0" name="Children" value="0" type="number">
                                                <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('.Children_N').stepUp()" class="plus"></button>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Adults</li>
                                        <li class="cart-free amount">0</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Children</li>
                                        <li class="cart-free amount">0</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>TOTAl COST</li>
                                        <li class="total">0$</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <a href="/booking-tour/" title="">‌BOOK NOW</a>
                        </div>
```

The details I think are clear in the picture. But this is how we enter the number of adults and children, and finally with jQuery we have to add the prices and show the final price.

These are html and css code. Unfortunately I do not have much control over jQuery to close the project.

Comment: Where is your JS?

Comment: Can you please add some CSS to make things look good ? Also please include js !

Comment: @Spectric I do not have much mastery of js and it is empty, so I am looking for help here.

Comment: Can you please explain how you are increase cost ... Or something like how to calculate

Comment: @Sanmeet I added css.

Comment: @SanmeetThere is a fixed price for adults and children, when the number of people is entered it is multiplied by the base price and finally the sum of the total price is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the inline onclick events from your buttons and added them back in as a programatic event listener. That way we can tie into these events to populate the prices. Rather than explain line by line, take a look and ask any questions you might have about how this works.

```js
let adultPrice = 19.99, childPrice = 11.99;

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.step-button');
  buttons.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', e => {
      let inc = -1;
      if (e.target.classList.contains('plus')) inc = 1;
      let input = e.target.closest('div').querySelector('input');
      input.value = Math.max((+input.value + inc), 0);
      calcAmounts()
    })
  })
  calcAmounts()
})

function calcAmounts() {
  document.querySelector('.adult-subtotal').innerHTML = '$' + (+document.querySelector('.Adults_N').value * adultPrice).toFixed(2);
  document.querySelector('.child-subtotal').innerHTML = '$' + (+document.querySelector('.Children_N').value * childPrice).toFixed(2);

  document.querySelector('.total').innerHTML = '$' + (+document.querySelector('.adult-subtotal').innerHTML.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '') + +document.querySelector('.child-subtotal').innerHTML.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '')).toFixed(2);
}
```

```css
.tours_description_book {
  border: 1px solid #d2ac67;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 9px;
}

.tours_description_book .title {
  background: #0c1e3a;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 15px 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.tours_description_book>ul {
  display: grid;
  grid: auto / auto;
  padding: 15px 35px;
}

.tours_description_book>ul>li>ul {
  display: grid;
  grid: auto / 50% 50%;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.tours_description_book>ul>li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdddf;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  color: #0c1e3a;
}

.tours_description_book>ul>li>ul>li:last-of-type {
  text-align: center;
}

.tours_description_book>ul>li:first-of-type>ul>li:last-of-type {
  text-align: left;
}

.tours_description_book>ul>li:first-of-type {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.tours_description_book>ul>li:last-of-type {
  border: 0;
}

.tours_description .tours_description_book a {
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
  margin: 0 auto 50px;
  background: #0c1e3a;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 9px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.tours_description .tours_description_book a:hover {
  background: #d2ac67;
}

input[type="number"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  appearance: textfield;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.number-input {
  border: 1px solid #d2ac67;
  display: inline-flex;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.number-input,
.number-input * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.number-input button {
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.number-input button:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '-';
  color: #d2ac67;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.number-input button.plus:before {
  content: '+';
}

.number-input input[type=number] {
  max-width: 4rem;
  padding: .5rem;
  border: solid #d2ac67;
  border-width: 0 1px;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 3rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="tours_description_book wrapper">
  <div class="title wrapper">- Booking -</div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>Adults
          <div class="number-input cart-free">
            <button class="step-button"></button>
            <input class="quantity Adults_N" min="0" name="Adults" value="1" type="number">
            <button class="step-button plus"></button>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>Children
          <div class="number-input cart-free">
            <button class="step-button"></button>
            <input class="quantity Children_N" min="0" name="Children" value="0" type="number">
            <button class="step-button plus"></button>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>Adults</li>
        <li class="cart-free adult-subtotal amount">0</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>Children</li>
        <li class="cart-free child-subtotal amount">0</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>TOTAl COST</li>
        <li class="total">0$</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <a href="https://iranro.co.uk/booking-tour/" title="">‌BOOK NOW</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, they did great.
This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You must use id's instead of a class where you want to make your element to be accessible uniquely ! .... Also instead of inline js use functions it will make your  code much cleaner ...

Since you didn't had any js so i wrote it accordingly..

See =>

**HTML**

```
<div class="title wrapper">
  - Booking -
</div>
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>Adults
        <div class="number-input cart-free">
          <button onclick="dec(this)" class="minus"></button>
          <input class="quantity Adults_N" min="0" name="Adults" id="Adults" value="1" type="number">
          <button onclick="inc(this)" class="plus"></button>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>Children
        <div class="number-input cart-free">
          <button onclick="dec(this)" class="minus"></button>
          <input class="quantity Children_N" min="0" name="Children" id="Children" value="0" type="number">
          <button onclick="inc(this)" class="plus"></button>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>Adults</li>
      <li class="cart-free amount" id="Adult_display">0</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>Children</li>
      <li class="cart-free amount" id="Child_display">0</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>TOTAl COST</li>
      <li class="total"><span id="total">0</span>$</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<a href="https://iranro.co.uk/booking-tour/" title="">‌BOOK NOW</a>
```

**JS**

```
  const adult_price = 100;
  const child_price = 20;


  const total = document.querySelector('#total')


  const adult_count = document.querySelector("#Adults");
  const child_count = document.querySelector("#Children");

  const child_display = document.querySelector("#Child_display");
  const adult_display = document.querySelector("#Adult_display");


  adult_display.innerText = adult_count.value;
  child_display.innerText = child_count.value;
  
  // Handling inc or dec
  function inc(element) {
    element = element.parentElement.querySelector("input");
    element.stepUp()
    count_change(element)
  }
  function dec(element) {
    element = element.parentElement.querySelector("input")
    element.stepDown();
    count_change(element)
  }


  // Adding listneres for change in values
  adult_count.addEventListener("change", function (element) {
    element = element.target;
    count_change(element);
  });
  child_count.addEventListener('change', function (element) {
    element = element.target;
    count_change(element);
  });


  // Upadte UI and calculate final price

  function count_change(ele) {
    if (ele === adult_count) {
      adult_display.innerText = adult_count.value
    } else if (ele === child_count) {
      child_display.innerText = child_count.value
    }
    calculate_price()
  }

  function calculate_price() {

    let total_price = parseInt(total.innerText)

     if (parseInt(adult_count.value) !== 0 && adult_count.value !== "") {
  total_price = parseInt(adult_count.value) * adult_price + parseInt(child_count.value) * child_price;

  adult_display.innerText = parseInt(adult_count.value) * adult_price + "$";
}

if (parseInt(child_count.value) !== 0 && child_count.value !== "") {
  total_price = parseInt(adult_count.value) * adult_price + parseInt(child_count.value) * child_price;

  child_display.innerText = parseInt(child_count.value) * child_price + "$";
}

    total.innerText = total_price;

  }

  calculate_price()
```